# How to exit a do-while loop using a Scanner in Java when the user enters the word "exit"?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that contains do while loop. I want the user to type **"exit"** in order to exit my loop, but my while statement doesn't work and generates an error.

The error is on the `}while(!integer1.equals("exit"));`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Integer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter integers or exit");
            int integer1 = sc.nextInt();
            int integer2 = sc.nextInt();
            if((integer1%integer2)==0)
                System.out.println(integer1+"divisible"+integer2);
            else
                System.out.println("Not divisible");

        }while(!integer1.equals("exit"));

    }

}
```

Comment: `integer1` is a int. An int cannot be equal to `"exit"`. `"exit"` is not a number. If your user types `exit` when you're trying to read an int, your program will error.

Comment: there should be an error message telling what is the problem: that would be helpful to help answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `integer1` is not accessible outside of the `do { ... }` block so can't use it inside the condition of the `while` statement. Even if `integer1` was accessible, you couldn't use the `equals` method because `integer1` is an `int` and primitve types don't have an `equals` method. ... and even if they had, an `int` is never going to be equal to a `String`, so you need to change the logic of program.

For example, you could use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = "";

    while (!(input = sc.next()).equals("exit")) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int i2 = sc.nextInt();

        if ((i1 % i2) == 0)
            System.out.println(i1 + "divisible" + i2);
        else
            System.out.println("Not divisible");
    }
}
```